# fgetcsv not reading mobile number columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, fgetcsv

i am trying to upload a `.csv` file.. and at the same time inserting the data from `csv` to `mysql` fr this to work i have written this:

CONTROLLLER:

```
$file_path = './public/projects/mycsvfile.csv';
if (($handle = fopen($file_path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($csv = fgetcsv($handle, 10000000, ',','"','\\')) !== FALSE) {
          $this->Dbmodel->insert_csv($csv);
    }
}
```

MODEL:

```
function insert_csv($csv) {
    $data = array(
        'project_name' => $csv[0],
        'task_type' => $csv[1],
        'company_id' => $csv[2],
        'mobile_number' => $csv[3]
        );
    $this->db->insert('projects', $data);
}
```

the above code works fine for me.. it fetch's all the data from csv to mysql database..

but when i see the results in the db..the column `mobile_number` only displays the first 3 digit out of 10.

ex: 978 instead of 9789789781

any suggest or help would be a great help.. thanks in advance

Comment: what is the field size of mobile number in db?

Comment: Output $csv[3] to check the output. It sounds like you have the db field limited.

Comment: it is int(11) ... is this right??

Comment: Phone numbers should be stored as strings. A number like "0114489456783" will have the front-end zero dropped if saving to an int field.

Comment: thanks every one i solved this..by changing the column type from `int` to `varcahr`